# Detects the sort order of the array

Tags: vba

There are several ways to arrange

```
1. table 1, table 2, table 3, table 4, table, 5；  that is right  
2. table 1, table 2, table 3, table 3, table 4, table 5； that is right  
3. table 3, table 1, table 2, table 4, table 5:  that is incorrect.  
4. table 3, table 1, table 2, table 3, table 4, table 5:  that is right.
```

I would like to mark the third case, but when I used my vba code, find the fourth case, it also will be given the error.
I hope you can give me some advice, when I detect the fourth case , the error is not reported.

```
   Sub tableOrder()
    Dim last_called As Integer, reference_by_numbered_list As Integer
    last_called = 0 
    selection.Find.Font.Bold = ture
    selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory
    'Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With selection.Find
        .Text = "Table [0-9]{1,}"
        .Format = True
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .MatchWildcards = True
        Do
            .Execute
            If Not .Found Then
            Exit Do
            ElseIf .Found Then
                last_called = tOrder(selection.Text, last_called)
            End If  
        Loop
    End With 
End Sub 

Function tOrder(AnyStr As String, last_call As Integer)
    Dim RegEx, mystr As String, myword As Words
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With RegEx
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "\d+"
    End With
        Set sql = RegEx.Execute(selection.Text)
        For i = 0 To sql.count - 1
    If Val(sql(i)) > last_call + 1 Then
        selection.Comments.Add Range:=selection.Range, Text:="incorrect citation order, table " & sql(i) & " detected before table " & last_call + 1 & ". "
    Else
    If Val(sql(i)) > last_call Then
        last_call = Val(sql(i))
    End If
    End If
        If i + 1 <= sql.count - 1 Then    'make sure there is still one entry ahead
        If Val(sql(i)) >= Val(sql(i + 1)) Then
            selection.Comments.Add Range:=selection.Range, Text:="detected " & sql(i) & " before " & sql(i + 1) & ". This is wrong citation order."
        End If
        End If
   Next i

  tOrder = last_call
    Set RegEx = Nothing
    Set dict = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: The way I see it 1. Is Sorted (asc), 2. Is Sorted (asc) including dupes grouped, 3. Is not sorted, 4. Is not sorted, so why is 4 correct? (What’s the pattern)

Comment: @ paul bica This function is to detect the order of the table cited in the article, and the customer required the way  (“4”) cited is correct.